# Prove that if $L$ is regular, then $f(L)$ is regular too

Tags: regular-language, regular-expressions

Prove that if $L$ is regular, then $f(L)$ is regular too.

$\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ are two arbitrary alphabets, $f$ is a function that maps every symbol of $\Sigma_1$ to an element in $\Sigma_2$, i.e., $f : \Sigma_1 \to \Sigma_2$.

$L_1$ is a regular language, $f^*(s_1s_2...) = f(s_1)f(s_2)...$ where $s_1s_2...$ is a string, and

$$f^*(L_1) = \bigcup f^*(w), w\in L_1.$$

The function $F(L_2)$ has following form:

$$F(L_2) = \{w\in \Sigma_1^* \;|\; f^*(w) \in L_2\}$$

1. Could you show that if $L_2$ is regular, then $F(L_2)$ is regular too.
2. Are this statements is correct:

   - $f^*(F(L_2)) \subseteq L_2$;
   - $L_2 \subseteq f^*(F(L_2))$;
   - $L_1 \subseteq F(f^*(L_1))$.

Comment: (*Replying to a comment that has since disappeared.*) $F$ is a function of languages. $F(L) = f^{*{-1}}(L)$, the inverse image of $L$ under $f^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L$ is a regular language, then it is defined by an extended (right-) regular grammar (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) $G$, whose rules are of the form:

- $B\to w$, for $B$ a nonterminal symbol, $w\in \Sigma^*$ (a string of terminal symbols);
- $B\to wC$, for $B,C$ nonterminal symbols, $w\in \Sigma^*$;
- $B\to\varepsilon$.

Given $f\colon\Sigma_1\to\Sigma_2^*$, use $f$ to create a new grammar $G'$ over $\Sigma_2$ by replacing every terminal symbol $a\in\Sigma_1$ in the righthand side of a $G$-rule with $f(a)$. The resulting grammar is easily seen to be an extended right-regular grammar, and the language it defines is $f^{*}(L)$; so $f^{*}(L)$ is also regular.

$f^*$ is a (monoid) homomorphism $\Sigma_1^*\to\Sigma_2^*$. The function $F$ maps languages to languages. For any $L\subseteq\Sigma_2^*$, $F(L) = f^{*{-1}}(L)\subseteq\Sigma_1^*$ is the inverse image of $L$ under $f^*$. If $L$ is regular, then so $F(L)$, because [the regular languages are closed under inverse homomorphisms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14785/are-regular-languages-closed-under-inverse-homomorphism).

Your last three statements are equivalent to these reformulations, and they are true, only sometimes true, and true respectively, *for any function, not just $f^*$*:

1. $f^*(f^{*{-1}}(L_2)) \subseteq L_2$: always true;
2. $L_2 \subseteq f^*(f^{*{-1}}(L_2))$: true only if $L_2\subseteq image(f^*)$;
3. $L_1 \subseteq f^{*{-1}}(f^*(L_1))$: always true.